# returning to default LOCK_TIMEOUT

Tags: sql-server, locking

After doing a `SET LOCK_TIMEOUT` in an SQL query is it possible to return to the default timeout? Or rather the default timeout as it was defined by the DBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is -1 which means "no timeout"

To reset it to the previous value that may not be the default in that connection, store the value from [`@@LOCK_TIMEOUT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182729.aspx) and change it back later. You'll need dynamic SQL.

However, it's reset when the connection is dropped as per [SET LOCK_TIMEOUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189470.aspx)

> At the beginning of a connection, this setting has a value of -1. After it is changed, the new setting stays in effect for the remainder of the connection.

So, unless you persist the connection indefinitely you don't need to do anything...